# Linq - Sql DateTime overflow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, .net-core

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

Whenever i try to save date into table this exception occured even if there is valid date is provided.

[image]

The save method looks below

```
Context.AccountStatusHist.AddRange(acStatusHist);

                await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How do i solve this issue
Thank you

Comment: `Context.SaveChangesAsync` is a EF method. Please show your entity and its problematic date field config. Are you sure, that the exception is thrown because of `AcStatusChangeDate` and not another date field?

Comment: What properties you have in AcGroup?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I dont want to insert AcGroup that is automatically mapped by ef core

Comment: I'll be willing to bet that somewhere you have an uninitialized `DateTime` property - which means it gets the default value of `DateTime.MinValue` which is way before 1753. About 1752 years before, if you want to be picky about it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can i identified which column does contain `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: Are you sure that ef core is not trying to insert new group entry and throwing error because datetime in AcGroup is not valid?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya AcGroup is auto generated due to foreign key with AcGroupId

Comment: You need to run profile on database and see what queries are executed. That will help you to figure out which query has invalid datetime value

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Profiler only shows exception but not actual query

Comment: Are you running SQL profiler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15